# Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem"

Tags: c#

I just moved to another pc and getting few similar errors to the one shown below. How may i fix it?

On this line of code:

```
   <Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl RepositoryUrl="$(PrivateRepositoryUrl)" SourceRoot="@(SourceRoot)" Hosts="@(SourceLinkGitHubHost)" IsSingleProvider="$(SourceLinkHasSingleProvider)">
     <Output TaskParameter="SourceLinkUrl" PropertyName="_SourceLinkUrlToUpdate"/>
   </Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl>
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4094 "C:\Users\Rob\.nuget\packages\;C:\Users\rob\.nuget\packages\" is an invalid value for the "SourceRoot" parameter of the "Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".    Appi.Application    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub\build\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.targets  36
```

Comment: "C:\Users\val\.nuget\packages\;C:\Users\rob\.nuget\packages\" <- These are 2. Choose 1. Because 2 are 1 too many. As the error message is trying to tell you :)

Comment: @Fildor how may i exactly choose 1 ?

Comment: Either "C:\Users\val\.nuget\packages\" or "C:\Users\rob\.nuget\packages\" - just try and fail or succeed.

Comment: @Fildor yes but where should i point to it? I understand the problem but do not know where to set it up

Comment: Ah, now I get it ... it comes from the `@(SourceRoot)` param ... I guess you'll have to investigate where that is set.

Comment: @Fildor Trying to find it but no idea where it might be.

Comment: If anyone face same issue here's how i solved it. I fixed it by going into each project folder and deleted `bin` & `obj` folders then by doing `Rebuild` errors disappeared. Note that Rebuild of project/-s itself without removing mentioned folders didn't work (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Arie's comment. Remove the bin & obj folders, then clean and rebuild the project.